Microsoft Word Template updating styles in just this one template file and have all other files originating from it automatically update
In MS Word we have a template document (template1.dotx). This document is used in SharePoint by many users to write thousands of procedure documents, saved as .mht or docx  documents.
As we update styles in template we would like to update all these other documents created from it.
Is it possible to update styles in just this one template file and have all these other files automatically update?
If not, what else can I do to update these thousands of documents with the changes to the template file?

Strictly speaking, this isn't a VBA question, since all you need do is check the 'Automatically update document styles' option under Developer|Document Template|Templates. Provided you do that for any existing documents based on that template, problem solved. Just be prepared for the howls of protest from all those who have misused the Styles...
